# Select2: Extend matcher for tag data

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, jquery-select2

I use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) for tagging purposes. It works like a charm, but i have an additional requirement: **The matcher should match more than only the text of the items.**

Let me explain. The `matcher` function takes two parameters, `term` and `text`. This allows us to compare the given tags and the entered text. But if i define additional data for each tag (via the `tags` function) i am unable to access it in the matcher.

Example code:

```
// #myinput is a hidden input field
$('#myinput').select2({
  matcher: function(term, text) {
      return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  },
  tags: function() {
      var tags = [];
      $('#myselect').find('option').each(function(index, option) {
          option = $(option);
          tags.push({
              id: option.val(),
              text: option.text(),
              category: option.data('category')
          });
      });
      return tags;
  }
})
```

I set the mandatory `id` and `text` properties for each tag. In addition, there is a string named `category`. I want to match against the text and the category instead of only the text.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not currently possible (as of 3.3), file an enhancement request with a jsfiddle in select2's github issue tracker.

Comment: it should be as easy as to pass the whole tag data object instead of data.text to the matcher (maybe as an additional parameter in order to maintain backwards compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Using 3.4.2, still not implemented. bu tthere is quite simple **hack**, really.

find in select2.(min).js line where matcher is called with 2 args ("*e.matcher(*");

on my version, i have something like this:

```
{var a=this.text!==b,c=a?this.text:this;(""===f||e.matcher(f,c)
```

add "this" to third arg

> e.matcher(f,c,this);

as result, entire tag object would be passed :)